# Decorative border css

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

I've been researching for a while and still can't find a way to make this border on css, so far I've made only one side.

[image]

I mean the same border with css not with the picture

Comment: can you share the code for the side you have made?

Comment: It was based on an example of another question http://jsfiddle.net/kywgsdjo/

Comment: You should add the code from your fiddle in the question itself. Also, you can check this question, the effect is almost the same : [Creating a droplet like border effect in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895895/creating-a-droplet-like-border-effect-in-css/)

Comment: If you have already some code working, and it is just a partial solution, you should **always** share your code in the question

Answer (score 2):

This is posible with css3. Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

First: define the width of your border, as you would usually do (`border: 30px solid...`);
Then specify the caracteristics of the image with border-image:

-You need to set the image with ulr().

-Then set in px (no units) or percentage (%) how to slice the image to create the borders. Notice that to tile the border the image gets sliced in 9 sectors. This number is the distance from the borders of this slice. For example, in a 300x300 px like in this case, if you slice it at 100, you are generating 9 squares of 100x100.

-Finally say if it should repeat, round or stretch.

A tip: this is a bit difficult so my advice is that you make your image tilable in a 3x3 grid, this way the corners will fit the sides.

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-image: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/2dh8y1g.jpg") 100 round;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Vendor prefixes arent very necesary any more: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

Comment: Thank you I'm trying this but with a svg. Let you know how it went