# How to make border with inside-radius?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with inside circle at the corner. It should look like the picture shown below

[image: https://habrastorage.org/files/01b/7bb/9cd/01b7bb9cd03e493c8a6cd16c5c904fa6.jpg]

Can someone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is solvable with css only. Have a look at this jquery plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Comment: If you need a `CSS` only solution, you can do something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/1aragjcf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, transparent 14px, red 15px) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 14px, red 15px) bottom right,
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 14px, red 15px) top right,
    radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 14px, red 15px) top left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

More info: [Inset border-radius with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033615/inset-border-radius-with-css3)

BUT (!) if you need more complexity on the shapes of that border, you could use a **background image or a border image**:

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-image: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/2dh8y1g.jpg") 100 round;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

More info: [Decorative border css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509710/decorative-border-css/30509904#30509904)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it makes perfectly good sense, although sometimes I can't think on a way of answering by referencing 2 or more posts and not copying their answers.