# Wave border in CSS

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

I know what you're thinking, there's at least a million questions like this, asking about waves in borders, or waves at the edges of elements. However, I have a different question. What I need is a combination between a [zigzag-edge](https://localmotors.com/blog/post/zig-zag-borders-in-css/1205/) (I have no idea how to call it, I'm not English) and a [wave-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css).

More specific: I need to create this:

[image]

The top part of the blue element has to be a wavy kind of border, where the top part is transparent so the underlying image shows 'through the element', so to say.

Is this do-able with CSS? I'd rather not use images, simply because there will be multiple elements like these, with different colours (that means different edge colours per element).

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895895/creating-a-droplet-like-border-effect-in-css/25903879#25903879. You can't exactly produce such a wave border effect with CSS (with a repeating pattern, unless you use a lot of elements). The closest is the thread I linked prior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Could the people giving me downvotes please tell me what the reason is for their downvote? I've did my research, I've come to a dead end, so far there's just one question that's related to mine (the one Harry linked), and I didn't find it in the search. What should I improve next time before I ask a question?

Comment: Shocking that they never answered the question above. Why is the SO community so toxic?!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's relatively easy to draw a border like that with a couple of pseudo-elements.

First we draw the bottom of the wave:

```css
.wave{
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, maroon 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wave'></div>
```

We then fill every other ditch with the background of another pseudo-element. This background is twice as wide so we only fill the odd ditches.

```css
.wave{
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, crimson 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wave'></div>
```

Combining the two gives us the desired effect:

```css
.wave{
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, aquamarine 13px);
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, aquamarine 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wave'></div>
```

---

Updated with a **flatter** wave.

```css
.wave{
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;  
}
.wave::before, .wave::after{
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 40px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px -15px, transparent 20px, yellow 21px);
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 26px, yellow 20px, transparent 21px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wave'></div>
```

Comment: Looks excellent. Very nice answer :)

Comment: This looks fantastic, thank you! I haven't gotten round to the elements yet that use the wavey edges, but I'm sure this will work perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly, but it is worth noting that this won't work in anything below IE10.

Comment: Excellently done.

Comment: man you are awesome!

Comment: How should one go about "flattening" the wave?

Comment: @cfraser Updated my answer with a flatter wave. You need a bigger circle / radius to make the wave appear flatter.

Comment: PO: _How long it would it takes to make a wave border here?_ . 
Me: _IDK, I guess it is possible in pure CSS, I'm not an expert, give me one hour_ . 
PO: _OK do it_ . 
***Five minutes later*** . 
Me: _Done!_ .

Comment: This is a really elegant answer man. Thanks!

Comment: You are an absolute life saver, my dude. Was beating my head against a wall all morning trying to figure out how to do this with an SVG in React, because I needed to color it dynamically. This is far more elegant.

Comment: Amazing solution! Any ideas how to modify this so that the lower part is transparent?

Comment: @Igor, Can you elaborate on what you mean by making the lower part transparent?

Comment: How do I flip it?

Comment: @woestijnrog the god !

Answer (score -1):

Try-

```
#wave {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 54px;
    background:#79C5BD none repeat scroll 0% 0%;float:left;margin-top:20px
}
#wave::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #79C5BD;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 27px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```css
#wave {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 54px;
    background:#79C5BD none repeat scroll 0% 0%;float:left;margin-top:20px
}
#wave::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #79C5BD;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 27px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div>
<div id="wave"></div><div id="wave"></div>
```

Comment: That is more of a droplet than a wave. When you compare with the image provided in question you'd notice that the bottom part is not curving.

Comment: What Harry said, yeah. I really need the wave, that's what the client wants. Besides, my Lead Dev won't like it if I use countless div's, just for aesthetic purposes..

EDIT: using thesame ID multiple times kinda goes against the purpose of an ID.