# CSS code to crop out square notches along an element's border?

Tags: css, border, crop, pseudo-element, background-subtraction

I'm creating a tile installation help website and would like to style an element's border to resemble a notched trowel:

[nothced trowel]https://www.flooranddecor.com/installation-tools-tile-stone-installation-materials/pacesetter-square-notched-trowel-100381193.html

Is it possible to crop out shapes at a specified interval to achieve this look?
What I've found so far is to use pseudo-elements to get the desired pattern, like this:

[Wave border in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759102/wave-border-in-css)

However, I need something that will subtract one from the other so that the border alternates between opaque and transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this! It's actually quite easy, I would recommend reading [This w3schools page on borders](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

I believe what you're asking could be done with left and up borders being solid and bottom and right being dotted (the same color as your background). I hope this helps

Comment: That would work if I was just using solid colors, but I'm trying to do an image over an image. I made a .png by cutting out squares with Paint.net to demonstrate: https://imgur.com/UBLnog0

Comment: @AlexErtl Can you elaborate on what your goal is a little more?

Comment: I would like to use it as a container for my navigation, so I'm trying to make it as dynamic as I can. The image I posted to imgur shows what it would like expanded.